# ts file is missing from the TypeScript compilation

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following a series of tutorial of angular. I've reach the part which I install this npm `npm install --save @angular/platform-server @nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader ts-loader`. Unfortunately upon running this line `ng run Udemy-Tutorial:server`

**Error**
[image: Error]

**Folder Structure**
[image]

**app.module.ts**

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: "my-app" }),
  ...
 ],
```

**app.server.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { ServerModule } from "@angular/platform-server";
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";

@NgModule({
imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppServerModule { }
```

**main.server.ts**

```
export { AppServerModule } from "./app/app.server.module";
```

and I've created the `tsconfig.server.json` contains the following code

```
{
 "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
   "types": [],
   "module": "commonjs",
},
 "files": [
 "src/main.ts",
  "src/polyfills.ts"
],
"include": [
"src/**/*.d.ts"
],
 "angularCompilerOptions": {
"entryModule": "src/app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
}
}
```

in angular.json added code

```
  "server": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/server",
        "main": "src/main.server.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json"
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try including all the `.ts` files in your tsconfig (now you are including two files and all the `.d.ts` files):

```
"include": [
  "src/**/*.ts"
],
```